# android upload large images

Tags: android, android-volley, android-networking

I want to create an app to upload large images (captured with smartphone so the size is over 3MB) to PHP server and a database with the path of the image. I have followed this tutorial with volley library https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/upload-image-to-server/
But I want to have two different buttons. One for selecting an image and another for uploading it. I know that I'm doing something wrong. Bcause it gives me `null` bitmap. I don't know what I have to change.

**Edit: MainActivity.java**

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.NetworkResponse;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //ImageView to display image selected
    ImageView imageView;
    String filePath;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //initializing views
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        //checking the permission
        //if the permission is not given we will open setting to add permission
        //else app will not open
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS,
                    Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
            return;
        }


        //adding click listener to button
        findViewById(R.id.buttonChooseImage).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                //if everything is ok we will open image chooser
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(i, 100);
            }
        });

        findViewById(R.id.buttonUploadImage).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //calling the method uploadBitmap to upload image
                uploadBitmap(filePath);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 100 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {

            //getting the image Uri
            Uri imageUri = data.getData();
            filePath = getPath(imageUri);

            //displaying selected image to imageview
            imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);
        }
    }

    // Get Path of selected image
    private String getPath(Uri contentUri) {
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(getApplicationContext(),    contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    Cursor cursor = loader.loadInBackground();
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String result = cursor.getString(column_index);
    cursor.close();
    return result;
}

    private void uploadBitmap(final String imagePath) {

        //our custom volley request
        VolleyMultipartRequest volleyMultipartRequest = new VolleyMultipartRequest(Request.Method.POST, EndPoints.UPLOAD_URL,
                new Response.Listener<NetworkResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(new String(response.data));
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), obj.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }) {

            /*
             * Here we are passing image by renaming it with a unique name
             * */
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                //Converting Bitmap to String
                String image = getFileDataFromDrawable(bitmap);

                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("pic", imagePath);
                return params;
            }
        };

        //adding the request to volley
        Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(volleyMultipartRequest);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should not mess around with a bitmap at all. The user chooses an image file. Then upload that file. data.getData() is the uri for the file. Use that uri to upload the file.

Comment: If you need original image then create a long-running connection with the api service so that your request doesn't timeout. Or else resize, scale, compress and upload the image.

Comment: I've changed the code but now toast shows Required params not available. It is from api.php.

Answer (score 0):

May be because in php the max size u can send is 2Mg, try te send a picture less then 2M , if it's work you have to go to php.ini and thange the max_size

Comment: The code was working fine with one button for selecting and uploading image no matter how MB was the image size. But I want to change the layout so it will have two buttons.

Answer (score 0):

i use this code for uploading files and i've not faced problems for uploading files over 14MB.

```
HttpURLConnection conn = null;
            DataOutputStream dos = null;
            String boundary = "*****";
            int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
            byte[] buffer;
            int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024;
            final File sourceFile = file_to_upload;

            String serverResponseMessage;
            String response = null;
            if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

                return "no file";
            } else {
                try {
                    FileInputStream fileInputStream =
                            new FileInputStream(sourceFile.getPath());

                    URL url = "upload_URL";

                    conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    int size = (int) sourceFile.length();
                    conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(size);
                    conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                    conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                    conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);


                    dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                    bytesRead = 0;
                    long total_bytes = 0;
                    Log.e("start", "" + size);
                    do {

                        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                        dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                        total_bytes += bytesRead;

                        float f1 = total_bytes;
                        float f2 = size;
                        float f3 = f1 / f2;

                        publishProgress(f3);
                    } while (bytesRead > 0);

                    int serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                    serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();
                    response = "HTTP Response is : "
                            + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode;

                    fileInputStream.close();
                    dos.flush();
                    dos.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();  
                } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                    e.printStackTrace();  
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();  
                }
            }
```